# Highchart - Is it possible to add data to series in stockchart.

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have seen this post [dynamically-add-data-to-series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049421/dynamically-add-data-to-series-in-highcharts) but its about adding a single point to the chart.

What I am looking for is on the stockchart initially load data e.g. from 2014 - 2016. And then on button clicked 'add more data, the chart adds the data from 2012-2014. But I don't want to loose the old data, just add the new data to the existing series. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes you can and it is the same function. Just call the addPoint method for each data point that you want to add. The addPoint method has a second parameter `redraw` which you can set to false so that the chart is not redrawn after each point that has been added.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`series.setData()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData) method. Simply, when new data arrives, concat new data with the old one (remember: data has to be sorted ascending by x-values) and use `setData(new_and_old_data)`.